# How to merge features and bug fixes over branches

Tags: tfs, branch

Simply put I have the following branch setup:

```
MAIN
   |--- DEV
   |--- PROD
```

Most developments are done in the DEV branch. When the code is ready to test, everything is merged to the MAIN branch and published to our test environment. When tests are completed, a merge to PROD is done and everything is published to the production server. Every now and then changes (mostly bugfixes) are made on the MAIN or PROD code, but this is an exception.

I have been asked to think out a system for feature and bugfix merging. This means that separate changes in the DEV should be merged across MAIN and PROD. With our current setup this information is lost: for example features A, B and C are implemented in the DEV branch. Let's say every feature has two corresponding changesets: A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2. With our current way of working, everything is merged to the MAIN branch in one go. So when we want to "cherry pick" features which have to go from MAIN to PROD we can't do this because there's only one changeset on MAIN: the checkin of the merge.

How would you fix this? Do I need to change something to my branching strategy?

I'm using TFS for source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > So when we want to "cherry pick" features which have to go from MAIN to PROD we can't do this because there's only one changeset on MAIN: the checkin of the merge.

You can write a tool to piece through the merge history, if you like, but the real answer is *don't do that*.  When you cherry pick, you lose any guarantee that the code you tested and stabilized in the source branch will perform the same way in the target branch.  Sometimes that's ok, but in your case it defeats the whole purpose of having an intermediate branch sitting between raw untested Dev checkins and your live PROD deployments.

As discussed in [my favorite branch/merge video](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-577744660535947210&ei=BAu0SqXsD5bWrQLz7Zj_AQ&q=laura+wingerd&hl=en#), your guiding principle should be "merge down, copy up."  That is, whenever the need arises to deconstruct and/or apply code diffs, let unstable branches take the hit.  (Cherry picking features out of an otherwise integrated app is one example.)  Meanwhile, code that's promoted up toward stable branches like Main & Prod should always be a straight copy that matches what you've already worked so hard to stabilize in the source branch.  Sounds like you're following this strategy currently; preserving it in the face of cherry picks would be my #1 motivation for using feature branches, even moreso than insulating feature teams from each others' breakages.

Managing dependencies between features is an issue, as Jim mentioned.  If you can identify them in advance, the usual solution is to make sub-branch(es) that are shared by the features with the common dependency.

```
Feature1
     \
    LibA---
     /     \
Feature2    \
           DEV -- MAIN -- PROD
Feature3    /
     \     /
    LibB---
     /
Feature4
```

Software doesn't always go as planned, of course.  And this doesn't work at all if the branches that need to share code are on opposite sides of the tree (e.g. if Feature1 depends on LibA *and* LibB, but Feature2 is ill equipped to be part of B for structural or technical reasons).

Comment: does anyone have a new link for that video?

Comment: I've found this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ-CpGsCpM0 which might or might not be the same video but is certainly interesting

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any magic sauce here, you've just got to find a system where you have a revision on main for each unit you might like to cherry pick.

This can be done trivially by merging each revision individually, which is a pain, but gets you what you want.

Alternatively, you can up the granularity, by merging each feature into main one at a time. This requires that you work sequentially on features, which may be ok if you're on your own, but will be a pain if there's a few of you, since you'll have to go through a code freeze where some people have finished and others haven't.

Another way of working which you may or may not find more manageable is to have a DEV branch for each feature. In this sense, instead of having an ever existant DEV branch, have a collection of ephemeral DEV branches that only exist until the feature is completed.

The reintegration of each DEV branch will give you a clear revision in main which can be cherry picked.

You can get dependencies between dev branches. Say branch devA needs some implementation from branch devB, you'll have to merge the required parts of devB into main and then merge them down into devA. However, devA shouldn't be needing unfinished work from devB, so you should (in theory) be able to RI those parts happily anyway. And of course, since you're cherry picking into PROD, these partial integrations don't have to get published.

Given your branching strategy, I guess you've already found this, but if not, it's worth reading:
http://branchingguidance.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=html&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Yes I've read that, thanks for the link. I think a partial solution to my problem is to start working with feature branches. Thanks for the answer.